# Sequelize Associations not showing up in pgAdmin

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am creating restApi endpoints for a social media app like Instagram.

There are 4 tables

1. User
2. Post
3. postLikes
4. postMedia

Associations...
A single user hasMany posts,
A single post belongsTo one User,
A post hasMany postLikes,
A post hasMany postMedias,
A postLike belongs to one post and belongs to one User,
A postMedia belongs to one post,

If u are still a bit unclear pls comment any help will be much appreciated.

**models/user.js**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      User.hasMany(models.Post, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        as: 'posts',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      });
      User.hasMany(models.postLikes, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        as: 'postLikes',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      });
    }
  };
  User.init({
    profile_img: DataTypes.STRING,
    firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    dob: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: DataTypes.ENUM('male', 'female'),
    token: DataTypes.STRING,
    is_deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

**models/post.js**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Post extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Post.hasMany(models.postLikes, {
        foreignKey: 'post_id',
        as: 'postLikes',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      });
      Post.hasMany(models.postMendia, {
        foreignKey: 'post_id',
        as: 'postMedia',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      })
    }
  };
  Post.init({
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    is_deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Post',
  });
  return Post;
};
```

**models/postLikes.js**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class postLikes extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      postLikes.belongsTo(models.Post, {
        foreignKey: 'post_id',
        as: 'post',
      });
      postLikes.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        as: 'user',
      })
    }
  };
  postLikes.init({
    post_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'postLikes',
  });
  return postLikes;
};
```

**models/postMedia.js**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class postMedia extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      postMedia.belongsTo(models.Post, {
        foreignKey: 'post_id',
        as: 'post'
      })
    }
  };
  postMedia.init({
    url: DataTypes.STRING,
    post_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    type: DataTypes.ENUM('image', 'video')
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'postMedia',
  });
  return postMedia;
};
```

After creating the associations in all the above models i am runnig the command
`sequelize db:migrate`

But when i open the **pgAdmin4** console i do not see any foreign key.

[image]

[image]

**P.S. I am referring to this article** https://dev.to/nedsoft/getting-started-with-sequelize-and-postgres-emp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the blog given above the, guy never told us that we have to add

```
      references: {
          model: {
            tableName: 'Users',
            schema: 'public'
          },
```

inside the migrations....

Refer this page... Just CTRL+F for foreignKey on the page and u will land there.
[Sequelize DOCS](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html)

Wasted 4+ hrs over this